# problem with QT and visual studio 2010 ultimate in debug build

Tags: qt

I install vs **2010** ultimate and "qt 4.7.1-vs **2008**" qt-vs-addin-1.1.7. Now every thing is configured but when i make a debug build of qt application i am getting 
"The application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect". 
This is probably because vs 2010 is compiling to msvcp100d.dll where as qt is compiled with msvcp90d.dll. Can you please let me know how the problem can be resolved thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

I'm not working with Windows releases for a long long time but if Nokia doesn't provides a compiled release for VS2010 why don't you compile Qt from the source? It takes a while but it's the right thing to do.

**PS:**

Looking through the Qt Software download page it doesn't seems to have a VS2010 release, at least for the LGPL version. Then, you really need to download the source and build it.

Just in case you need from reference on Qt build process, take a look at this:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Opticks_Developer_Guide/Getting_Started/Building_Qt_From_Source

Configure options for you case may be different.

Also, be warned that according to [this](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/supported-platforms.html) VS 2010 is not a Tier 1 platform for Qt.